# TFS support / configuration in Project Rider

Tags: tfs, rider

I'm trying to configure my `Project Rider` (build `RS-163.3419 from August 27, 2016`) to work with `TFS`. I'm setting configuration of Version Control in Settings:

[image: TFS configuration]

but whenever I'm trying to do anything `TFS` related I get:

> Error:Mappings not found for file '...'

Am I doing something wrong or `TFS` is not yet supported in `Rider` EAP version?

**EDIT**: What I'm expecting is what I know from other Jetbrains IDE's and `git` support which is highlighting changes in file inline (new/modified/deleted line) as shown below
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have tested installing riderRS-163.3419.exe (Windows), the TFS Integration plugin has been bundled with Rider and enabled by default.

[image]

The usage is similar to in IntelliJ IDEA, check [Using TFS Integration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/using-tfs-integration.html).

Comment: please check my edit: I described what I'm expecting to have as a TFS support feature

Comment: Do you use TFS Integration plugin? Is it able to version control your project by TFS?